# reset a python list, making all elements 0

Tags: python, list, reset

I have an python list without knowing how many integer elements it contains.
for some reason I want to reset all elements to 0. as below

```
[0, 0, 0, 0......]
```

How do I do it?

Comment: `lst = [1,2,3] lst= [0 for x in lst]`

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @balderman that doesn't actually set the elements of the list to 0.

Comment: @balderman That does not affect the list object at all. And it creates a spurious second list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree. But it "feels" like it is not important if a new list is being created.

Answer (score 2):

You can use slice assignment:

```
lst = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

lst[:] = [0 for _ in lst]
```

Slice assignment makes sure that the original list is actually mutated. Otherwise (`lst = ...`) you are just rebinding the (possibly only local) variable.

Comment: Where do I see the space usage in that tool?

Comment: The claim I make is that the generator uses `O(1)` space, not `O(N)` as another list object, say `lst[:] = [0 for _ in lst]`.

Comment: Ah I see. That case is very interesting, in deed.

Comment: It also makes sense for a pseudo assignment (it's a mutation, I know) to completely evaluate the right-hand side before "assigning". But true, for a lazy iterator that must require some way of storing the elements.

Comment: Actually, slice assignment always creates a list out of the iterable, so it is not in fact constant space. If you want constant space, use a loop

Answer (score 0):

If your list is called `data`

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,4]
```

you can either create a new list of all `0`

```
>>> data = [0]*len(data)
>>> data
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

or use a list comprehension

```
>>> data = [0 for _ in data]
>>> data
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Both of these create a new list, to be clear

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Correct, though I didn't gather from the OP that this was against their requirements?

Comment: The OP isnt clear, but in your answer you state "you can **either** create a new list of all 0 **or** use a list comprehension" which could be taken to mean that the list comprehension doesn't create a new list